# What to do when keyserver.ubuntu.com is down?

Tags: gnupg

What happens if I upload a revoke key to another keyserver different to the Ubuntu keyserver; will they be sync automatically?

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is Yes, with the addition of "sooner or later".

Whatever the sync happens sooner or later depends on what alternate key server you choose. A good choice is picking another one of the [SKS Keyservers](http://sks-keyservers.net/).